# Communication within custom Directives in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have create three directive

```
 app.directive('directiveOne',function(){
   return 
   { restrict: 'E',
     controller: function($scope){
     $scope.elements = {};
     this.funOne = function(){
            $scope.elements.item1 = "value 1";               
        }
     this.funTwo = function(){
            $scope.elements.item2 = "value 2";
        }
    }
   }
 });

 app.directive('directiveTwo',function(){
 return{
    require: "directiveOne",
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attribute, directiveOneCtrl){
      directiveOneCtrl.funOne();
    }
   }
});

app.directive('directiveThree',function(){
return{
    require: "directiveOne",
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attribute, directiveOneCtrl){
      directiveOneCtrl.funTwo();
    }
  }
});
```

when I access them in my view only one directive is executed (only second directive is executed)

```
    <directive-one directive-two> {{elements.item1}} </directive-one>
    <directive-one directive-three> {{elements.item2}} </directive-one>
```

May I know what is the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that none of your directives have their own scope, so all are sharing the same scope. When directive-one's controller is instantiated the second time, you reset the value of $scope.elements to an empty object.

To test this, try adding `scope: true` to the directive-one definition object. That will give each instance of directive-one its own scope.